# I am trying to create a favourite content btn but i am getting the ( AttributeError at /contents/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'favourite' )?

Tags: python, django

My HTML code:

```
          {% for i in content reversed %}
          <div class="col-lg-4 content"   data-aos="zoom-out-up" data-aos-duration="800">
            <div class="card card-body cardbody">
              <h4 class="content_title">{{ i.content_title }}</h4><hr>
              <img src="/media/{{i.content_img}}" class="content_img"><hr>
              <div class="favourite-section">
                {% if is_favourite %}
                  <a href="{% url 'favourite_content' id=i.id %}"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i></a>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="{% url 'favourite_content' id=i.id %}"><i class="far fa-heart fa-lg"></i></a>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>    
          {% endfor %}
```

Here is the urls.py file

```
path('', views.contents, name="contents"),
path(r'(?P<id>\d+)/favourite_content', views.favourite_content, name="favourite_content"),
```

Here is the view.py file

```
def contents(request):
    content = Content.objects.all()

    is_favourite = False
    if content.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_favourite = True

    params = {'content': content, 'is_favourite': is_favourite}
    return render(request, 'contents.html', params)

def favourite_content(request, id):
    content = get_object_or_404(Content, id=id)
    if content.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        content.favourite.remove(request.user)
    else:
        content.favourite.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(content.get_absolute_url())
```

Here is the models.py code

```
favourite = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
```

How to edit the views.py file so it is registered in the database that the user has favorited this video ?

Comment: you are making wrong thing.
try following thing `Content.objects.filter(favourite=request.user).exists()`

Comment: When it comes to the AttributeError, you get that because of the following part:
`content = Content.objects.all()`
`if content.favourite.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()`
`Content.objects.all()` returns a QuerySet. A QuerySet does not have the model's attributes. Only model instances have those attributes. You can read about [QuerySet methods that return new QuerySets in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets). You can get a model instance by using a method that does not return a new QuerySet, e. g. Content.objects.first().